# Why does Qt generate a .cpp file out of .qrc?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, build, qmake

Qt generates a .cpp file when compiling the resource, e.g. images, which are defined in the .qrc file. The compile output is as follows:

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/bin/rcc -name images ../myApplication/images.qrc -o qrc_images.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../myApplication -I. -I../shared_base/Debug -I../shared_base -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtQuick -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtMultimedia -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtQml -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtSql -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o qrc_images.o qrc_images.cpp
```

So as seen in the output, to compile the `image resources`, two different commands are executed, the `rcc` and the `g++`. 
However, one can simply compile the `images` with the `rcc` and register this binary file in the application during run time. I can't understand what this `g++` command does and why it is necessary.

Also why does qt include libs such as `Multimedia`, `Gui`, etc. into this file and make it larger than just the images?

Note: The images folder is sized 27MB. The generated images.cpp file is sized 66MB and if I compile the images with the rcc-utility myself it is also 27MB and it works just like the 66MB did.

Comment: `rcc` utility generates a .cpp file out of your resources. The compiler compiles it in order to embed it into your binary.

Answer (score 2):

> ...one can simply compile the "images" with the rcc and register this
>   binary file in the application during run time.

As @vahancho pointed out, Qt resources can be loaded dynamically too if you generate a binary resource data with `-binary` option of `rcc`. That file can be loaded with `QResource::registerResource()` function.

> I can't understand what this g++ command does and why it is necessary.

It builds the object file, which is then linked into the binary at a later stage.

> Also why does qt include libs such as Multimedia, Gui etc into this
>   file and make it larger than just the images?

Including the libs doesn't necessary mean the binary will be larger. Linker will produce a binary only with those objects that are used in your code.

Comment: Qt resources can be loaded dynamically too if you generate a binary resource data with `-binary` option of `rcc`. That file can be loaded with `QResource::registerResource();` function.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware about this. Thanks :)

Comment: Let me say it this way: I tested 2 different ways, I let Qt do all the work, which generated the output above, and it made 66MB sized .cpp out of 27 MB sized images folder. Then I deactivated the Qt-part and did it myself by externally compiling the images with the rcc-utility and the output was exactly 27MB. Then I loaded it dynamically and it worked just like the first option.

Comment: cpp file, that was build by rcc, is just an intermediate file when compiling. I do not understand your concern. This file is not being shipped in with the source code, it is produced during the build.

Comment: I think cpp file is not produced by rcc, but by the g++ command right after that. What is the difference between the registerResource() method and cpp method? Pros/Cons?

Comment: *I think cpp file is not produced by rcc, but by the g++ command right after that.* You are wrong: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/rcc.html  
*Pros/Cons?* Please ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `cpp` file generated by `rcc` is bigger, because every `byte` in images will become `0x00` code in cpp.

If your file is 100KB, the `cpp` file may be 500KB, it's ok.

The final executable file will not so big, binary is binary, cpp is cpp.